# Error creating CloudFront Distribution: NoSuchOrigin:

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to deploy a Cloudfront distribution with Terraform and getting an error while specifying the origin_id

Cloudfront is pointing at a load balancer via a Route53 lookup.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my-app" {
  origin {
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 443
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }

    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "Custom-${var.domain_name}"
  }

...

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${local.origin_id}"

...
```

where `var.domain_name` is a route53 record and `local.origin_id` is a unique id.

When performing the terraform apply I get this error:

`aws_cloudfront_distribution.my-app: error creating CloudFront Distribution: NoSuchOrigin: One or more of your origins or origin groups do not exist.`

The documentation states: `origin_id (Required) - A unique identifier for the origin.` which it is.

Comment: what is `domain_name`? is it an S3 bucket?

Comment: Are you defining the same originID in the cache behavior ?

Comment: @StephenG no it is a route53 record

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error relates to the cache behaviour.
You need to make sure that the `target_origin_id` relates to an `origin_id` within a cache behaviour.

Like so:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my-app" {
  origin {
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 443
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }

    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "Custom-${var.domain_name}"
  }

...

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "Custom-${var.domain_name}"

...
```